# Selecting distinct set of tags from HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get set of distinct tags from an HTML DOM using jQuery/JS?

Below is sample DOM

```
HTML  
-- Head  
-- META  
-- TITLE   
-- H1  
-- BODY  
-- DIV 
-- DIV  
-- FORM  
-- INPUT
-- INPUT
-- INPUT
```

then output should be

```
HTML  
HEAD  
META  
TITLE  
H1  
BODY  
DIV  
FORM  
INPUT
```

thanks
iuq

Comment: By using the selectors that jQuery provides: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. I'm not really sure what answer you're expecting here.

Comment: Betting you want `*`

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it clarifies!

Comment: No repeated linear searches this way: `var names = Object.keys([].reduce.call($("*"), function(obj, el) { obj[el.tagName] = 1; return obj; }, {}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the node names of all elements, then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the duplicates:

```
// Get all tag names
var tags = $("*").map(function() {
   return this.nodeName; 
}).get()
// Filter out the duplicates
.filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
console.log(tags);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wsbj4pt/)

You could replace jQuery's map with the [in-built one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in conjunction with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if you don't want jQuery at all:

```
var tags = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"), function(e) {
   return e.nodeName; 
}).filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
console.log(tags);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70yzgx7p/)

Answer (score 2):

In Vanilla JS and as function:

```
function getDistinctTags() {
    var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'));
    return els.reduce(function (result, el) {
        if (result.indexOf(el.tagName) === -1) {
            result.push(el.tagName);
        }
        return result;
    }, []);
}
```